# Trouble Getting Columns Names to Variable in SSIS Execute SQL Task

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm attempting to validate some column headings before the import of a monthly data set. I've set up an *Execute SQL Task* that's supposed to retrieve the column headings of the prior month's table and store it in *Header_Row* as a single string with the field names separated by commas. The query runs just fine in SQL Server, but when running in SSIS, it throws the following error:

```
"The type of the value (Empty) being assigned to variable 'User:Header_Row' differs from the current variable type (String)."
```

1) Does this mean that I'm not getting anything back from my query?

2) Is there another method I should be using in SSIS to get the query results I'm looking for?

3) Is there an issue with me using the variable reference in my query as a *portion* of a string? I think the answer is yes, but would like to confirm, as my variable was still empty after changing this.

**Original Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    STUFF((
            SELECT
                ',' + COLUMN_NAME
            FROM
                db_Analytics.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS aa
            WHERE
                TABLE_NAME = 'dt_table_?'
            ORDER BY
                aa.ORDINAL_POSITION
          FOR
            XML PATH('')
          ), 1, 1, '') AS Fields
FROM
    db_Analytics.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a;
```

EDIT: After changing the variable to cover the full table name, I have a new error saying "The value type (__ComObject) can only be converted to variables of the type Object."

**Final Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CAST(STUFF((
            SELECT
                ',' + COLUMN_NAME
            FROM
                db_Analytics.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS aa
            WHERE
                TABLE_NAME = ?
            ORDER BY
                aa.ORDINAL_POSITION
          FOR
            XML PATH('')
          ), 1, 1, '') As varchar(8000)) AS Fields
FROM
    db_Analytics.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with the query above:

**1)** The query in the task was not properly parameterized. I fixed this by putting the full name of the prior month's table into the variable.

**2)** The default length of the result was MAX, which was causing an issue when SSIS would try to put it into my variable, *Header_Row*. I fixed this by casting the result of the query as varchar(8000).

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really pretty sure that this is your problem:

```
TABLE_NAME = 'dt_table_?'
```

I'm guessing this is an attempt to parameterize the query, but having the question mark inside the single-quote will cause the question mark to be taken literally.

Try like this instead:

```
TABLE_NAME = ?
```

And when you populate the variable that you use as the parameter value, include the 'dt_table_' part in the value of the variable.

EDIT:

Also in your ResultSet assignment, try changing "Fields" to "0" in the Result Name column.

Comment: I think you're right that it is *a* problem, but not the only one. When I make the change you mention, I still get the error but with *DBNull* in place of *Empty*.

Comment: You might have problems where you a) assign the variable to the query parameter and/or b) assign the query result to the output variable.    But you would need to add screenshots of those assignments for us to be able to help.

Comment: Added to the post. Result set is setup as a single row result set.

Comment: The 0 in Parameter Mapping just tells it which *?* to replace with the given parameter. Happens to be 0-based. *Fields* is needed because that's what I called the result column in the SQL query.

Comment: Yes, but not all providers make the column name available to SSIS in the single-row resultset.   Using 0 to indicate the first column in the result set is always supported.   Did you try it?

Comment: Ah, okay. I did. No change. Though I didn't notice a new error after fixing the variable issue. "The value type (__ComObject) can only be converted to variables of type object." A quick googling says there may be an issue with the length of the result. I'm going to take a look at it now.

Comment: That's an error I would expect to see if you were attempting to assign a full resultset (not single row) to a non-object type variable.   Is it possible that this is happening in some other part of the package?

Comment: Not likely. The only tasks I have enabled are the *Execute SQL Task* and then a *Script Task* to compare the query results with some CSV headers. I tried casting the query results as a varchar(8000) and that seems to have done it, though I need to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to parameterize your query. *Proper* query parameterization is useful for avoiding SQL Injection attacks and the like.

Your query is looking for a `TABLE_NAME` that is literally 'dt_table_?' That's probably not what you want.

For laziness, I'd just rewrite it as

```
DECLARE @tname sysname = 'dt_table_' + ?;
SELECT DISTINCT
    STUFF((
            SELECT
                ',' + COLUMN_NAME
            FROM
                db_Analytics.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS aa
            WHERE
                TABLE_NAME = @tname
            ORDER BY
                aa.ORDINAL_POSITION
          FOR
            XML PATH('')
          ), 1, 1, '') AS Fields
FROM
    db_Analytics.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a;
```

If that's not working, you might need to use an Expression to build out the query.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure how SSIS would interpret the position of the *?*. I'm getting Null now, which is *something*, just not the right thing.